# ScreenOS: See Peak bandwidth on an Interface and Alarm if it crosses a threshold

Tags: juniper, monitoring, screenos

I have a Juniper SSG320M running ScreenOS 6.2 (actually 2 of them in an HA active/passive).

I want to measure the bandwidth consumed on one of the interfaces, and throw an alarm if that exceeds a certain threshold (e.g. >1Mbit/sec).  Is there some way to do this with the native functionality in ScreenOS?  I searched for this, but could not find an answer.

Note that I am interested in both ingress and egress bandwidth.

Edit:  Any type of alarm will do.  It can simply be a message in the log that I can grep for later.

Comment: Are you looking for any specific type of notification?

Comment: @Fizzle Question updated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set alarm thresholds on policy rules[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlS0k.png). Would that suffice? I haven't found another way to do this. I would use an external host and read the counters using SNMP.